# Is it legal for the compiler to degrade the time complexity of a program? Is this considered observable behavior?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

<sub>(*Note: This is intended to be a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) question; I'm not referring to any particular existing compilers.*)</sub>

When, if ever, is the compiler allowed to degrade the time complexity of a program?
Under what circumstances (if any) is this considered "observable behavior", and why?
(For example, can the compiler legally "reduce" a polynomial-time program to an exponential-time one?)

If the answer differs in C and C++, or in different versions of either, then please explain the differences.

Comment: By "degrade" you mean that it gets worse? I have a hard time seeing HOW the compiler could do that, since nearly everything to do with O is based on the overall algorithm, and I fail to see how the compiler can make that worse (it may possibly recognise what you want to do and make it better in some rare cases, but that's not the same thing)

Comment: I believe that an infinitely fast -or arbitrarily slow- computer is standard C and standard C++ compliant.

Comment: There's at least one easy answer: when undefined behaviour occurs! Does the standard even have anything to say about userland complexity?

Comment: Obviously, my comment applies to "valid code", not UB or similar. (Actually, I have a hard time seeing how UB is supposed to make the O worse, without also failing to produce correct result)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I dunno, I can think of a lot of examples. Can a compiler replace binary search with linear search for example, perhaps on the grounds that it thinks this may be faster for smaller arrays?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Well the nice (or damning?) thing about time complexity is that it has nothing to do with the speed of the machine you're running the program on.

Comment: @user657267: Wow nice, looks like you found the trivial solution. :-)

Comment: I have never seen such a behaviour, and I definitely don't think that would be legal. Unless the array is fixed size with known content and the compiler resolves the entire thing - but I doubt that is happening.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: If that wouldn't be legal then why would the reverse direction (which actually *does* happen) be legal then?

Comment: @Mehrdad: with an *inifinitely* fast computer, every terminating computation has the same time cost.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: By "infinitely fast" do you mean a [hypercomputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation#Hypercomputer_proposals)?

Comment: Reverse direction search (don't think I've ever seen that)? Or just reverse direction of the loop-count (which I have seen)... Or a reverse direction memset/memcpy/fill-loop? A reverse direction search would absolutely kill the performance of searching a sorted list, for example (and the compiler may not KNOW if you have sorted the list, for example in a different compile-unit, or read it from a sorted file).

Comment: @MatsPetersson It will kill performance, but the question is not about performance. It's about time complexity.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Sorry, by "reverse direction" I meant if a compiler is permitted to turn linear search into e.g. binary search (assuming it's provably correct) then why wouldn't it be permitted to do the reverse?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think the compiler is not allowed to convert any search algorithm, that is eventually the standard library implementation.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: Well, it may be an algorithm that ISN'T part of the set used by the library, perhaps. I doubt very much that the compiler converts searches from linear to binary search either "on it's own accord". Certainly I've never heard of it (aside from possibly if the searched entries are compile-time known)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I explicitly said *"I'm not referring to any particular existing compilers"*.

Comment: So, you are referring to a pessimising, not yet written compiler, produced to consume as many clock-cycles as possible, which is produced by some evil company that pays for it to be used, to force us to get new, faster processors? Like the answers already written, there is no legal restrictions on what the compiler can do. But it would be insane and/or stupid to spend all that effort to recognise searching or sorting (etc), and "make it worse". Note there is also no rule saying the compiler can't introduce 100 extra instructions for every "real" instruction... ;)

Comment: Reading from or writing to haphazard addresses in a "random" order may touch hardware registers in an inadequate order or cause page faults or DMA transfers, or have other unexpected and possibly devastating results which are not just _somewhat slower_ (think persistently mapped buffers in GL). Insofar, I think it is very clear that the compiler cannot just change an access pattern as it pleases (such as linear/binary search). It _might_ reorder some singular reads and writes under well-defined conditions, but surely not use a radically different algorithm.

Comment: @Damon: Hardware memory concerns are irrelevant unless the pointer target is volatile.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, such "pessimization" is unlikely and contrary to the intent of any "rational" compiler.  But, in doing an optimization, the compiler could "pessimize" in in some cases, eg, where a loop iterates only one time, but the compiler generates a lot of pre-loop initializations to make the loop faster.  Offhand, though, I can't think of any that would change the "order" of the algorithm (to make it worse, that is).

Comment: It would be reasonable for a compiler to perform operations multiple times and take the majority result, for example in systems expected to operate in high magnetic fields or ionising radiation. That's a special case and not relevant to conventional compilers, but the standard should not forbid such special cases for special purposes.

Comment: So we are talking about the O(X), so that 100 extra lines for each really needed line won't change the complexity. O(101X)=O(X).

Comment: Although your question is not about any existing compilers, that would be an interesting question in itself: is there a real-life example of a piece of source and two actual compilers which generate code of different asymptotic complexities?  (Even more interesting if it doesn't involve standard library functions, which could easily be implemented in better or worse ways.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The C standard doesn't actually have a time complexity model, neither for its primitive operations, nor its library functions, so compilers are allowed to do pretty much anything that preserves program semantics (observable behavior).

The C++ standard only gives complexity guarantees only for some its library functions, and says (17.5.1.4 [structure.specifications]):

> Complexity requirements specified in the library clauses are upper bounds, and implementations that provide better complexity guarantees satisfy the requirements.

A compiler better preserve these bounds (and since many of the functions are templated/may be inlined, the compiler is involved), but the bounds are in terms of the number of elements in containers and restrict the number of calls to comparison operators and the like. Otherwise, the compiler is again free to do as it pleases.

Comment: This makes for a very good comment (+1), but it's not an answer for C++ at least, since this isn't concerning library functions, but rather user code.

Comment: @Mehrdad The answer actually says that there is nothing in the standard that prohibits the compiler from degrading performance. Since the mentioned clause in the C++ standard is an exception, it should be mentioned in the answer. So the above answer should be read as: Neither the C nor the C++ standard prohibits the compiler from degrading the time complexity of user code.

Comment: @Mehrdad Many (maybe all) of the functions with time bounds are templated functions, which will be expanded by the compiler.

Comment: If you want to know the time complexity of user code, then you need to know the time complexity of user code calling library functions, so this answer is just fine.

Comment: The complexity requirements only specify "number of X operations", e.g. X = "calls to the user's `operator <`" or X = "calls to `std::swap`"

Answer (score 24):

Performance of the code is not considered observable behavior and could potentially be modified by the compiler in either direction. In practical terms, for *quality of implementation* (QoI) reasons compilers don't degrade your programs, but there are cases where QoI is not performance.

A compiler, given the appropriate flags, could add instrumentation to the program it is building for debugging purposes (this is often the case in library implementations, for example with checked iterators).

Note that the simple answer to *when* the compiler would degrade your program is twofold: when the client asks for it, or when the implementor doesn't want to have users for the compiler.

Answer (score 15):

5.1.2.3 in the C standard says

> The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an
>   abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant.

The C++ standard has similar wording in 1.9 [intro.execution]

Both standards have the same definition of observable behaviour:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>   — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract
>   machine.
>   — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
>   execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>   — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in
>   7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output
>   appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to
>   a program waiting for input.
>   This is the *observable behavior* of the program.

So anything else, e.g. performance of a `for` loop, or the number of reads/writes done for non-volatile variables, is not considered observable and so there are no corresponding performance requirements on the compiler.

If the compiler wanted to re-evaluate a block of code 100 times (assuming it had no observable side-effects, only altering the state of non-volatile variables) and check that the same results were obtained every time (and not affected by cosmic rays or faulty hardware) that would be allowed by the standard.

Comment: But even executing all code 100 times (minus the side effects) does not change the time complexity. To achieve that, the compiler should either do something like build ever longer delays (as the loop advances) into loops, or replace the code written by something completely different (but with the same observable behaviour). Either way, the program is necessarily spending more and more time without any obserable behaviour at all.

Comment: Either  way, the compiler is allowed to do that, because it has the same observable behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

Others have pointed out that the standard doesn't constrain how the C runtime works, only its observable behaviour. There is no reason why you can't have interpreted or JIT-compiled C, for example.

Consider a C implementation where all memory cells are stored in a linked list on some underlying system. Pointers are then an index into this linked list. All pointer operations would function as normal, except the runtime would have to iterate over the linked list on every memory access. All sorts of common algorithms would suddenly gain an extra factor of N in their complexity, for example the common null-terminated string operations.