# Is infinite loop is considered "run time error"? (c)

Tags: c

I have this question:
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    float s;

    for (s = 100000001.0f; s <= 100000010.0f; s += 1.0f) {
    };

    printf("SLABC\n");
 
return 0;

}
```

it's infine loop becuase the float thing. But Idk if that's conbsidered "run time error" or "prints nothing"

Comment: "Run time error" usually means "crash".  This doesn't crash.

Comment: The assumption here is that `float` can't exceed a particular value, like `16777216.0`.

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you use a version earlier than C11, since universities most often teach the older versions. If not, check out M.M's answer.

Anyway, we can have a look at all answers:

1. **Doesn't compile**: this is false. This program perfectly compiles. It might give a *warning* however, which is not the same as an *error*.
2. **Causes a runtime error**: no. This code just keeps running. It will remain inside the `for` loop for eternity and beyond (or just close the program and don't be dramatic). The same for point 3.
3. **Prints SLABC**: no. It stays inside the `for` loop. Read point 2 for extra information.
4. **Prints nothing**: this is the correct answer. There are no errors, the program will just execute everything.

Your program is essentially like my list. If you followed it correctly you would be stuck between point 2 and 3 and never be able to read point 4. But you are smarter than that.

Comment: A nice and funny answer. If I could, I would upvote twice

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Although it is incorrect since C11

Comment: @M.M it is indeed incorrect since C11, however I'm assuming he is a university student. They still teach earlier versions in most of the universities. Your answer does explain it better than mine. But OP is probably new to C, so I tried to keep it a bit understandable.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to add "prior to C11" to the answer, as modern compilers could do any of the above.  The latest clang exits the process with error status, and godbolt-gcc gives a runtime error.

Comment: @M.M I have added a reference to your answer in my answer.

Comment: Note that C does not mandate any particular precision for `float` -- just a minimum precision.  So an implementation might use a higher than minimum precision that will result in the loop terminating.  There are machines that do not support less than 64-bit floating point precision in hardware.

Answer (score 5):

Since threads were added to C (i.e. the C11 standard), there is a *forward progress guarantee*. Every loop must either do something or exit, and there's an exception for "intentional" infinite loops such as `while(1)`.

The text from C11 6.8.5/6:

> An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression, that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a `for` statement) its *expression-3*, may be assumed by the implementation to
> terminate.

Your program falls into this case, since the loop condition is not a constant expression, as it involves a variable `s`.

So the program may behave as if the loop terminates, i.e. it may carry on to print `SLABC` and exit.  Or (dependent on the properties of `float` on your implementation of course) it may stay in the loop forever and output nothing.

The purpose of this clause is to allow the optimizer to remove empty loops, without having to prove that the loop would eventually end . Or in other words, [runtime complexity is not considered part of the program's observable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26230791/1505939), unless hanging forever is intentionally signalled by a `while(1)` or similar.

*Note:* it can be argued that attempting to execute such a loop means the behaviour is undefined , since the standard doesn't have anything to say about what it means for a loop to terminate in this manner (e.g. what values might `s` hold after the loop?). If this argument is accepted then any other result is possible, including compilation error.

clang (trunk) does appear to treat it as undefined behaviour, aborting the program when execution reaches the loop. [godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vY73oq7nf).  The godbolt implementation of gcc-10.2 also causes a runtime error after some amount of time passes (which is not non-conforming since the loop may be assumed to terminate).

Comment: A related case in C++ (where even a constant controlling expression doesn't make it well-defined) - [What clauses of the latest C++ standard say this loop is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75848478) - there's a `return true` in an `if` in the loop, but no other way out.  Clang assumes that the `return true` must eventually be reached, because the alternative (infinite loop) would be UB.

Comment: @PeterCordes That post has been deleted by author unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the heads up that the link is stale.  https://godbolt.org/z/zh37qoK3h has the code from it, for future readers that want a concrete example of that `if() return true` inside an infinite loop.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to run this program on online c complier

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
        char a = 0;
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
...Program has been killed (because output is larger than 20 MB)
```

after executing for some time the program gets terminated automatically. This depends on the size of the complier's memory.

```
Prints Nothing
```

is your answer.